# Python selenium tab feature works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I am working on the below script to open multiple website in new tabs. This is working fine in Firefox as expected.

But it is not working in Chrome. It opens a new tab as the second tab, but the second website link opens in the first tab itself. Later again a new tab is opened as the third tab, then the third link opens in the first tab itself. The commented part ( 5 th line ) is how I call the chromedriver.exe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  #Chrome('C:\\data\\books oae\\apex library\\chromedriver') #Firefox() 

browser.get('https://trello.com/login')
time.sleep(10)
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('user')
emailElem.send_keys('test123@gmail.com')
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
passwordElem.send_keys('test12345')
passwordElem.submit()

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

browser.get('https://todoist.com/Users/showLogin')
time.sleep(10)
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
emailElem.send_keys('test123@gmail.com')
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
passwordElem.send_keys('test12345')
passwordElem.submit()

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

browser.get('https://asana.com/#login')
time.sleep(10)
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('login-email-login-modal')
emailElem.send_keys('test123@gmail.com')
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('login-password-login-modal')
passwordElem.send_keys('test12345')
passwordElem.submit()
```

Comment: what `selenium` version you are using?

Comment: In `Linux` I can open new tab in `Chrome` with `JavaScript` (`browser.execute_script("window.open()")`), but in `Firefox` it opens a new window

Comment: @dm295 the selenium version is 2.48 and the chromedriver version I use is 2.21 and I am running this script from Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: I was able to open 3 different tabs in `Chrome`, but I can't switch between them with `browser.switch_to.window()`

Answer (score 0):

[Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is the answer to your problem. It's a wrapper around Selenium that does all your Display-handling for you. Just by creating new Splinter objects, you open new windows. You can specify if you want them to be Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: let me try to implement the same using Splinter and get back to you in case of any issues.